# About my relationship with my mentor

Tags: phd, advisor, mentoring

I can not evaluate my relationship with my mentor. I'm in a really bad mood. For example, I went to talk to him today because he told me he would visit to my office to talk, but he did not. He had left already. Should I send an e-mail? I'm very confused about this.

Like this, he also had physical therapy, so he could not come into the office for one month, but in the meantime he did not reply to any of my e-mails. He didn't even say when he would arrive. I saw him come by chance. The other PhD student knew, but because he was writing his thesis, they needed to talk.

I was humiliated and I think he hates me. I know he is very busy but he could tell me at least "see you later." Interestingly, he is kind to people.

What I should make of this situation?

Comment: Is there a cultural difference between you and your advisor? I might feel annoyed by this but never humiliated.

Comment: I assume when you say "mentor" you actually mean "advisor" or "supervisor"? As I found at some point, despite "mentor" being the correct word for "supervisor" in my native language, it has a different meaning in English

Comment: I meant 'advisor'.

Answer (score 7):

I'd guess you are overreacting and overthinking this. Perhaps he forgot. Perhaps he had something very important come up. It is even possible that he did come, but you had stepped out momentarily and he missed you. Physical therapy might have been necessary. Lots of things.

Don't expect professors to return email immediately. It isn't like you are a group of chatty friends. Email can be an annoyance that needs to be managed. You didn't say anything about the contents of your mail. "Dear Professor Jerk,..." isn't going to win you any points. (Sorry, but you said you are in a bad mood.)

I think it exceedingly unlikely that the professor "hates" you. Equally unlikely that they intentionally humiliated you.

If this happens repeatedly over a period of time then you have cause for complaint, but professors are no more perfect than anyone else. Relax.